# Coordinates of an image PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm making an application for which I need to extract the coordinates of the image on mouse click.
The images have a resolution of **1920x1080** and the resolution of my laptop screen is **1366x768**.

I'm facing two problems here. 1) The images shows up in a cropped manner on my laptop. 2) Whenever I click the mouse button it gives me the coordinate of my laptop screen not of the image.

I strictly don't have to resize the image and secondly, in my final project the image would not occupy the entire screen, it will be occupying only a portion of the screen. I'm looking for a way to show the entire image as well getting the coordinates with respect to the image.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys


class Window(QtGui.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('image.jpg'))
        self.mousePressEvent = self.getPos

    def getPos(self , event):
        x = event.pos().x()
        y = event.pos().y()
        self.point = (x, y)
        print(self.point)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    w = Window()
    w.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here is an image which will give you an idea about my final project.

[image]

Comment: Uhm. I don't understand. 1. You say that "in my final project the image would not occupy the entire screen", so why do you complain about the cropped image? 2. the mousePressEvent.pos() is *always* relative to the widget, not to the screen, I don't understand why you say that it gives you screen coordinates, because it doesn't.

Comment: @musicamante I have shared an image which will give you an idea about my final project.

Comment: @musicamante 1. What I meant was that the image should not appear as if it has been cropped. I need the full image, but that image will not occupy the entire screen because there will be some additional infomation displayed along with that image (just like in the image above). 2. I want the coordinates of the top-left corner of the image to be (0, 0) and bottom-right to be (1920, 1080), maybe ```mousePressEvent.pos()``` is not the right function to use here but I think I have made it clear enough now.

Comment: So you want the image to be *scaled*. Should it keep the proportions?

Comment: @musicamante Yes it should.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using QLabel you should use QGraphicsView as it has the advantage of easy scaling and easy handling of coordinates

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class GraphicsView(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.setScene(scene)

        self._pixmap_item = QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem()
        scene.addItem(self.pixmap_item)

    @property
    def pixmap_item(self):
        return self._pixmap_item

    def setPixmap(self, pixmap):
        self.pixmap_item.setPixmap(pixmap)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.fitInView(self.pixmap_item, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        super().resizeEvent(event)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if self.pixmap_item is self.itemAt(event.pos()):
            sp = self.mapToScene(event.pos())
            lp = self.pixmap_item.mapFromScene(sp).toPoint()
            print(lp)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = GraphicsView()
    w.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("image.jpg"))
    w.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Will it work just fine or a video/camera also? If not then what changes would I have to make?

Comment: Generally I do not answer questions that do not have to do with my answer but I think they do (with some limitations), for example this code: https://github.com/eyllanesc/QtExamples/tree/master/others/not_classified/1 does something similar to what you want. I will not continue answering another type of question that does not indicate a problem with my current code

Comment: I'd add a couple of suggestions, since the program might use `setPixmap()` more than once. In the `setPixmap` (after setting the pixmap for the item) it's also better to add `self.setSceneRect(self.pixmap_item.sceneBoundingRect())` and another call to `self.fitInView(self.pixmap_item, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)`. Also, to avoid the default graphics view borders, `self.setFrameShape(0)` can be added in the `__init__` too.